# Why I am getting this Json.Parse syntax error in response?

Tags: angularjs, json, parsing, syntax

I am making the frontend in angular and backend in Yii2. I am hitting an api the status is Ok, but in response I get syntax error. It was working yesterday but I dont know why it is not working now

[image]

How can I parse the array if i get nothing in the response????

Comment: your json format might be wrong.Why dont post your json?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use online parser tool in order to understand what is wrong with your json data. I can recommend you http://json.parser.online.fr/